# Built-in Chrome PDF Viewer does not fully load large PDF file for authenticated users in ASP.NET Web App

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, pdf, pdfium

The Built-in Chrome PDF Viewer does not fully load large PDF files for authenticated users.

Steps to reproduce in my environment:

1. In Visual Studio 2019 create a new `WebForms` project with `Individual User Accounts` authentication
2. In `solution explorer` create some folder e.g. `MyPDFs` and put inside some large [pdf file](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/a17/A17_FlightPlan.pdf).
3. Secure this folder with `web.config`:

   `<location path="MyPDFs">
     <system.web>
       <authorization>
         <deny users="?" />
       </authorization>
     </system.web>
   </location>`

   and for this testing purposes set `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` to `true`:

   `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">`
4. Run this site with IISExpress and navigate to `~/MyPDFs/A17_FlightPlan.pdf` in my case it is `https://localhost:44302/pdfs/A17_FlightPlan.pdf`
5. The login screen appears, after user successful logins the pdf is **partially rendered (only first page)** by built-in Chrome PDF viewer (pdfium) 
   [image: partially rendered image]
6. When you remove authorization rule from `web.config`, or you put the PDF file to some other location, it is loaded correctly
7. The same behavior I can reproduce on production - Full IIS
8. Other browsers work fine: FireFox, EDGE, or even Chrome with replaced built-in PDF viewer for Adobe Acrobat reader extension

Where could be the problem? Are the headers OK?

[image: Response headers]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in Google Chrome. In Chrome Version `81.0.4044.43 (Official Build) beta (64-bit)` it seems working.

Comment: Any official source to find more details about this bug